# Marking objects from view for later use

Tags: views, media, ubercart

If I have a table containing, say, images, how can I be able to select an image from one view, one from another and have them added/marked for later use (i.e., some sort of "add to cart" feature). So then I could select an image from slideshow1, one image from slideshow10 etc and then be able to do whatever I want with them (perhaps create another view?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect job for [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module.

From the module description:

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, or users. Some
>   possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag
>   as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom
>   lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.

For your use case, I would create a new flag for your image content type. Add the flag operation to your current views of images. Create a new view that uses that flag as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

[Write an action](http://drupal.org/node/172152) and use it with [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

Comment: Can you please explain further? I'm quite new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking of selecting an image from a view, and another one from a different view, then I think there is nothing that allows to do that.

The closer I can think of is something that allows you to select nodes shown in a view, and apply an operation to those nodes. This is what the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module does.
This is an example of what the node view that comes with the module outputs.

[image: screenshot]

I installed the [Image module](http://drupal.org/project/image), which has support for the Views module, and in the VBO view I added the field for attached images.

[image: screenshot]

As result, the view now shows what visible in this screenshot. I could have removed any not necessary fields from the view, and obtained a more compact view.

[image: screenshot]

The list under "Bulk operations" contains all the operations that can be done to the selected nodes, and includes also what other modules export as node operations (through [hook_node_operations()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_node_operations/6)) or as actions (through [hook_action_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_action_info/6)).
Ubercart exposes some actions too; if those are applicable to nodes, then you should see them in the bulk-operations list. If they don't appear, or they are not the actions that you need, then you need to create a custom module, and implement one of the hooks I reported.
VBO has also the "Execute arbitrary PHP script" operation, but it would execute the code that users would enter when selecting that operations; it doesn't always execute code that you decided.

VBO also allows you to select which operations to show in the view; this means you can remove all the operations that are not necessary in your view, and show only the operations exposed from your module.